# Proper way of sending a NON JSON response from a cloud function Parse-platform with express

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform

i need advice on an obviously newbee parse-platform question. 
i have a following cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("create-links", function(request, response) 
{
  try
  {
    var links="";  
    var clientMeta= JSON.parse(utils.decryptFromUriCapable( request.params.clientKey,'base64'));
    model.serviceType.assertValidQuizParams(request.params);

    [.......] 
     return response.success(links);

  }catch(e)  
  {
    utils.logError(e);
    return response.error(utils.errorResponse(e));
  }
});
```

but the the client, which is making a post request on "create-links", expects a plain text as an answer and not the JSON encoded object containing a result: property provided by response.success() function.
when i look into the code of the parse server, it becomes obvious where JSON formatting comes from

```
 static createResponseObject(resolve, reject, message) {
    return {
      success: function(result) {
        resolve({
          response: {
            result: Parse._encode(result),
          },
        });
      },.......
```

***i  do undestand, i can directly use*** response.send() of the underlying express/node.js 
***but i wonder if this will break*** any of the logic or state management of the parse server functionRouter.
so what is the clean and proper way of sending a non JSON response from a cloud function?

Comment: You won't be able to do that with cloud code functions. The closest that you can do is something like this: `{ "result": "your string goes here" }`. If you really need to return a plain string, you will need to create a custom route in your Express.js application for that.

Comment: this is a clear cut answer,thank you Davi,